# exit python program without close Tkinter window

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

when I was working with Tkinter in python, I encountered an interesting problem that when I run a python program in Linux Terminal, my code opened a Tkinter widget like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Hello World")
txt = Text(root, width=60, height=20, wrap="word")
txt.insert(INSERT, "HELLO WORLD")
txt.insert(END, "---------------END---------------")
txt.config(state=DISABLED)
txt.bind("<Leave>", close_when_lost_focus)
txt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and then I force quit python program with `Ctrl + Z`, the Tkinter window was still there and I couldn't close it until I closed the Terminal.
Any body knows what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

control-z doesn't force quit a program. It is more like putting it to sleep, or suspending it. You can cause the program to resume by typing the command `fg` (foreground) or `bg` (background).

`fg` brings it to the foreground, which makes it as if you never typed control-z.

`bg` places the job in the background and lets it continue running while allowing you to type additional commands in the terminal.

For more information see [What is effect of CTRL + Z on a unix\Linux application](https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application)

Comment: Because of that, the Python script stops executing. Once brought back to the foreground process group, it'll start processing the previously generated events when the script was asleep.

Comment: thank you for that, I thought `ctrl + z` and `ctrl + c` are all force quit command :))